# Overriding CSS of div inside a #shadow-root

Tags: css, styles, shadow-dom, shadow-root

We are using a third party plugin and im trying to override the CSS of one div in particular. The problem is that i dont understand how you are suppossed to work with #shadow-root

[Image with shadow-root code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CF1uU.png)

I have tried using regular CSS to style to override the .choice--size-small div styling but its not working

```
div.choice--size-small{
  display:none!important
}
```

My understanding is that  #shadow-root purpose is to isolate everything that is inside so it doesnt get affected by other CSS, so it makes sense.

Can it be done? what is the best way to achieve this?
Keep in mind this is a third party software and we can only us CSS and JS to achieve this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That 3rd party has provided **"part"** *attributes* (only some elements) you can use to style the inside of the shadowRoot, without using JavaScript.

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::part

[image]

so your CSS can be:

```
sc-choice::part(base) {
  display: none;
}
```

When an **open** shadowRoot has no `part` definitions. You can *"get in"* with:

```js
document.querySelector("sc-choice").shadowRoot.append(
  Object.assign(document.createElement("STYLE"),{
                           innerText : `div.choice--size-small {
                                          display:none
                                        }`
  });
)
```

Comment: Welp. That solved it, thank you so much, i cant believe it was that easy. 

Thank you so much!

Comment: Although I've not figured out how to do this in TypeScript React. +1 for the hint, though.